# 3D Interpolation

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpolation

I try to reformulate my problem clearer :

I want to make a 3D interpolation of my data but I can't find the good `scipy` to solve my problem and the right way to handle it.

Imagine that you are in a 3D cartesian space `(x,y,z)`. The `(x,y) ==> (200x200)` plane is faced to you and you can see the graphic representation of some values forming a scatter plot. The values are estimated by a model which look at the properties of my object in a specific wavelength. The model that I use can handle only a total of 20 wavelengths, this is our `z-axis`. So if we took again our graphic representation of my problem, you have 20 layers of plots starting from a value called `lambda_min` reaching the 20-th and last wavelength : `lambda_max`. Each layers of plot are separated by regular steps. But as you can guess, since we have a limited number of models generated(20), we can't get an estimation of the values between the gaps : this is the purpose of my question.

How can we interpolate the data `(y)` for one or more specific wavelengths `(z)` not generated by our model. I precise that the `x` value sampling is the same for all the models the only changing parameter in the `(x,y)` plane with respect to the wavelength is the estimation of the physical quantity `(y)`.

My data are sorted in an array called `V` (called from the quantity I work with : Visibilities) of shape `(10,200)`.

So when I call `V[w][k]` this give me a point : the estimated Visibility`(y)` estimated for a given `w` (= wavelength ==> `z`) at a specific point `k` on the `x-axis` (=`q` spatial frequency).

The `x-axis` data (spatial frequency) are stored separetly in a 1D array called `q` of length `200` and is the same for all the wavelength.

Comment: So what (2?) files do you want to interpolate between for a given wavelength?

Comment: @martineau I would like to make interpolation among the whole set of data. I will precise with an example :
If I have 5 files with 5 different wavelengths between 3µm and 10µm for each file I have x-axis an y-axis values (2 columns of length K). I want to inteprolate my data and at the end enter only the wavelength that i want giving as output the y-axis values (knowing that the x-axis value is fixed over all the files).

Comment: The same way that you use scipy.interpolate.interp1d when you just enter an x value to interpolate, here i want to insert an W value to have as output the corresponding list of y-values.

Comment: I tried to reformulate my problem for a clearer representation of my problem. @martineau

Comment: Julien: As far as I can tell your question (now) has a good enough explanation — it's just not in my area of expertise.

Comment: Well ok, thank you anyway ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to a friend of mine and @Chris answer i realized that the problem was not a 3D but 2D problem and then I tried to use one more time the `scipy.interpolate.interp2d`.

Then in order to estimate the V value that i want for a given wavenlength at a specific spatial frequency.

```
f = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(x=q,y=wavel,z=V)
```

where

```
np.shape(q) = (200,)
np.shape(w) = (10,)
np.shape(V) = (10,200)
```

When i tried it the first time my problem was the to invert the x and y values and then the error was induced by an error of shape. But now I defined better my problem, and then we realized that by inverting the x-axis and y-axis we're now good using this method.

Answer (score 1):

Base on your question it sounds like you have the following problem. Correct me if I am wrong:

```py
x = [1, 2, .., 200]
y = [1, 2, .., 200]
z = [z0, .., z20]

V = V(z, k, y) = V(z, k(x), y)
```

You say you know `V` for all `x`, `y` and `z` given above. And know you want to know them for real numbers `y'` and `z'`, where `1 < y' < 200` and `z0 < z' < z20`.

So we are interestd in:

```py
res = V(z', k(x), y')
```

Did I get that correctly?

If so, we have a 2d interpolation problem. Take [`scipy.interpolate.interp2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html) and feed it with the correct data.

For a given `val_x in [1, 2, .., 200]` you do the following:

```py
all_y = np.arange(1, 200 + 1)
all_z = [z0, .., z20]
all_V_x = [[V(z, k(val_x), y) for y in all_y] for z in all_z])

estimate_V_x = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(all_y, all_z, all_V_x, kind='cubic')
```

Now we have our a function to get estimates of `V` for `z'` and `y'`, for our given `val_x`. We just need to evaluate it:

```py
res = estimate_V_x(y_new, z_new)
```

This gives us the result for `V(z', k(x), y')`.

To plug it all together:

```py
all_x = np.arange(1, 200 + 1)
all_y = np.arange(1, 200 + 1)
all_z = [z0, .., z20]

def get_V(z, k, y):
    assert z in all_z and y in all_y
    return ... # your computed data goes here
def get_k(x):
    assert x in all_x
    return ... # your computed data goes here

def estimate_V(x, new_y, new_z):
    assert x in all_x
    all_V_x = [[get_V(z, get_k(val_x), y) for y in all_y] for z in all_z])
    estimate_V_x = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(all_y, all_z, all_V_x, kind='cubic')
    return estimate_V_x(new_y, new_z)
```

Note that here `new_y` and `new_z` can also be arrays, to speed things up.

I am not sure if I got things right, or if this makes any sense. Let me know.

Comment: Hey @Chris thank you for your response, in fact 'y' is the value V, 'x' is the spatial frequency and 'z' the wavelength. What I want is to know the value of V for a given 'z' among my x-axis interval points (then create a new scatter plot with all the interpolated values of V for this wavelength) and after make a 1D interpolation among the new bench of estimation of V for a given 'z' to target a point 'y' with respect to 'x'. The last point I can do it by 1D interpolation of scipy but the other one I don't get the way to do it since 'z' has a length different from the x and y axis.